# Why doesn't my field assignment work for lightning:recordEditForm?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-recordeditform

I have a component with a `lightning:recordEditForm` that I build using an `aura:iteration` over fields from a field set for Order Products. I've added a custom submit method in my controller that makes sure that all required fields have values:

```
var fields = evt.getParam("fields");
fields.OrderId = cmp.get("v.recordId");
fields.PricebookEntryId = cmp.get("v.currentFs").pbeId;
fields.Product2Id = cmp.get("v.currentFs").prodId;
fields.Quantity = 1.00;
fields.UnitPrice = 0.00;
```

When I fill out the form and submit in my component, though, it gives me an error that when I log it to the console says I have a field integrity exception on `UnitPrice` because "Order Products must have a unit price."

I just moved this component from a scratch org into a company sandbox, and I didn't have this issue in the scratch org. I've tested to make sure my value actually gets saved to the `fields` variable, and I don't know where else to check for what's wrong.

What else might be a factor in this?

Comment: check for validation rule if any. your scratch org might be missing the validation rule.

Comment: I hadn't thought about that, but I don't have any validation rules on `UnitPrice`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[@Ashish Sharma](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/44906/ashish-sharma) made a comment about validation rules breaking the form, and it prompted me to check workflow rules too. I had a rule that populated the value of `UnitPrice` with a value from a field that did not always have a value, and it looks like that was the issue.

Comment: Great, you were able to fix it. Please close the thread by accepting your answer.